# Laravel multiple guard in blade

Tags: laravel

How make multiple watch same div to admin and manager using middleware?

Admin middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isRole() == "Administrator"){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('login');
}
```

Manager middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isRole() == "Manager"){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('login');
}
```

And AppServiceProvoider

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::if('admin', function () {
        return auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role == "Administrator";
    });

    Blade::if('manager', function () {
        return auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role == "Manager";
    });
}
```

Comment: you mean how to use it in blade?

Comment: Example home.blade.php : @ admin <div class="test"> Hello </div> @ endadmin It's working, but if I want -> @ admin OR @ manager it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not do this?

```php
    Blade::if('managerOradmin', function () {
        return auth()->check() && (auth()->user()->role == "Administrator" || auth()->user()->role == "Manager");
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to use admin and manager on one line using || or && ?

Comment: Thansk, I didn't know why I didn't try this one :D